# Play Framewrok object serialization with Akka

Tags: java, playframework, akka, object-serialization

I have a play framework 2.0 connected  to a remote akka systems in java language. I have a java array list object wrapped in a message class. the problem is that I want to send the message object to the remote akka system for computation. So , I want to know do I need to deploy the message object or do I need to serialize the message object. Can someone help me with a good explanation on the best choice and how to do the implementation.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the wrapper class implement Serializable and put it in the message object, Akka should take care of the rest.  (Sorry I can't be more helpful but stuff like this is much easier to deal with in the Scala version)

Comment: by message object do you mean an akka actor

Comment: No, the object that is passed between them